# how do you set @synthesize for an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

How do you set @synthesize for an array like: float rgb[3]. Also, is the @property line: @property(nonatomic, assign) float rgb?? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that you can define the array size in the interface if you wish you use it as a property. You would need to do something like: (pardon any syntactical mistakes, this is from memory)

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    float *rgb;
}

@propery (nonatomic, assign) float *rgb;
```

Then in your implementation:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize rgb;

@end
```

Then you would have to initialize the pointer using some C functions, such as:

```
rgb = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);
```